# Persist javascript changes on the server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side, server-side

Does any body know how to persist javascript changes on the server side.
For example if I added items to a drop down list client side, how can i persist them in order to read them on the server side.
By the way, **Telerik** control have this feature.

Comment: I've run into this issue before, I got around it by appending the values of the listbox (although drop down list should be just as easy) to a hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions doesn't contains any details, so I can only give you a generic answer:

You have to post the new data back to the server, either by using AJAX (I'd suggest using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)) or by sumbitting the new data in some field (preferably hidden) with a regular html-form (can be done in JavaScript or by having the user click "submit").

Comment: Do you have a sample or an article about how to do it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the server what the Javascript did using AJAX or a hidden field.

Comment: Do you have a sample or an article about how to do it exactly.

Comment: @Ghyath: You're asking how to send an AJAX request?

Comment: No i know how to send an ajax request, but what should i send in this ajax request.

Comment: Whatever you want to tell the server about the changes.